# Cannot kill process nomachine nxnode.bin

Tags: arch-linux, kill

Almost every time, when I resume system from sleep mode, after login again with `nomachine` (remote desktop) I have:

- process `nxnode.bin` with **R** (realtime?) and **100% CPU usage**.

This makes impossible login through `nomachine`. Normally this process is not in the `R` state and does not consume 100% of a core.

My question is: How I can kill such process?

Here is what I see from `htop`:

```
  PID USER     PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
13888 usr        0 -20 11.6G  340M 81688 R 100   1.1 1:00.06  nxnode.bin
```

After running `kill -9 13888`, the process is still present.

after `poweroff` or `reboot` machine doesn't turn off/reboot physically as it usually does.

Comment: `R` is running/runnable not realtime.  The nice value (`-20`) gives it the highest scheduling priority.  Does your `kill` command produce any output?

Comment: @AndyDalton there is no output after kill

Comment: After killing the process, you say it's still present.  Does it still have the same PID?  Are you sure that `kill` didn't kill it?  Could something have restarted it?

Comment: maybe something is wrong with htop because I don't see this pid after `ps -ef`. But still cannot turn off machine properly